# Drop cache does not work

Tags: linux, caching, memory, memory-management

I am currently working on optimizing the memory management of a large program. For some pupose, I want to drop the page cache in my main memory.

I used `sync &&  echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches` as widely suggested by the internet, but it does not drop the cache to the level where it was before the program starts. This means there are some undroppable cache in the main memory after the program starts.

But isn't `echo 3` means to **free pagecache, dentries and inodes in cache memory**? Is there any other kinds of cache that cannot be freed by this command?

Comment: How are you determining that caches have not been dropped?

Comment: I used the values in `free -m` and `htop` before and after.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are some types of caches that cannot be dropped. For instance, `tmpfs` filesystems are stored in page cache. But these could not be flushed while in use. You can get better picture of how much memory you really have available by using `free` command, and checking `available` column. You'll notice that available memory is smaller than free + buffers + caches. Sometimes much smaller.

For more information on `tmpfs` using caches see [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/1035758/152903).

Answer (score 0):

Collect output of cat /proc/vmstat before and after you issue drop cache.

It will give nr_inactive_file,nr_active_file ,nr_file_pages,nr_isolated_file. If drop cache works then total of above 4 should be less than before issuing drop cache.